# Backend - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have installed joomla 3.3.6 and I had no troubles installing it. I login as super user, and everytime I try to change any element (menu, items, modules) it displays the `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error. I think this might be due to permissions restrictions. But I am loging in as super user.

What may be causing this error?

best regards

Comment: Have you tried Googling this error and attempted doing what others have suggested?

Comment: Ofc I google this error, but didn't find any solution that's why I posted it here.

Comment: Anyone facing this issue ?

Comment: Maybe a more descriptive error might popup if you would watch the error log of the web server its running on? You could also try the developer console for your browser. Chrome for instance has a Network tab. Maybe checking "Preserve log" and then refreshing the page will give you more information (redirects gone bad for instance).

Comment: Ah, apparently this is somewhat of an old question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Google Chrome error rather than a Joomla issue.

You can find out more at:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84313

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be just Chrome interpretation of 500 error code.

Setup your Joomla and server to do error reporting. And you might face your devil.